# get checked value of ToggleButton (react-bootstrap) using refs in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap, react-dom

I have used a toggle button from react- bootstrap (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#btn-groups-checkbox-radio) in one of my form in react application. I want to get the **checked** value but it is always showing me **undefined**. Other form controls are getting easily. Please, help. Below is the code:

```
    <Row>
         <Col xs={12} sm={8} md={6}>
                    <FormGroup controlId="journeyType" validationState={ this.props.validation }>
                      <ButtonToolbar>
                        <ToggleButtonGroup type="radio" name="journeyType" defaultValue={"cheapest"} ref="journeyType">
                          <ToggleButton value={"cheapest"} bsStyle="primary">Cheapest</ToggleButton>
                          <ToggleButton value={"fastest"} bsStyle="primary">Fatest</ToggleButton>
                        </ToggleButtonGroup>
                      </ButtonToolbar>
                      <FormControl.Feedback />
                    </FormGroup>
    </Col>
</Row>
```

and in my react function, I am using below:

```
const sortQuery = {
      departure: findDOMNode(this.refs.departure).value,
      arrival: findDOMNode(this.refs.arrival).value,
      journeyType: findDOMNode(this.refs.journeyType).value
    };
    console.log(sortQuery);
    this.props.handleSort(sortQuery);
```

In above code, departure and arrival have values from the user but the **journeyType** always have **undefined**. It is because, react-dom is rendering the **ToggleButtonGroup** as radio inside divs. Even if used, `journeyType: findDOMNode(this.refs.journeyType.checked).value` , also not working.

Hope to hear from you, all. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can call your function in the `onChange` function of the `ToggleButtonGroup`.
If your `onChange={handleChange}`, then,

```
handleChange = (slectedButtonNumber) =>{
  //slectedButtonNumber= the 'value' of the selected radio button
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think with radio buttons we use `.checked` instead of `.value`.  So there is no need for the `.value`.

Try `journeyType: findDOMNode(this.refs.journeyType).checked`.